# How to add each element of a list to a new list using Python?

Tags: python

I'm currently scraping TikTok videos, and one of the results returned is an array with hashtags that looks like this:

```
[]
['ColdplayXBTS', 'MyUniverse']
['mi11Ultra', 'photography', 'autumn', 'fypシ', 'jordikoalitic']
[]
[]
[]
[]
['couple', 'amour']
[]
['lifehack', 'viral', 'funny', 'funnyvideos', 'remix', 'comedy', 'challenge']
```

I'm trying to create a new column in my dataset and add each hashtag in each row, like this:
[image]
I've tried to create a loop in order to create a new list, but it didn't work...

```
for tiktok in tiktoks:
    videodescription = tiktok.get('desc', {})
    hashtags = re.findall("#(\w+)",videodescription)
    hashtags2 = []
    for sublist in hashtags:
        for item in sublist:
            hashtags2.append(item)
```

(The result of the code above)
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

So reading this I believe the desired output is just an array of hashtags. If so, this should work.

```
hashtags2 = []
for sublist in hashtags:
    hashtags2.extend(sublist)
```

The .extend() method essentially adds the new list into the current one, such as:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
list1.extend(list2)
print(list1) # This will print [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Then you can go ahead and add your hashtags two list into the dataframe as you'd like.

Comment: Also watch your identation!

Comment: Thanks for the help! unfortunately, it's not working, as it's returning the same result as I had before (letters are separated individually, instead of the entire hashtag).

Comment: Could you please show us the output of the list hashtags?

Comment: yes, of course, just updated the original post with it.